# Dynamic file saving using cells values in vba

Tags: excel, vba, file, save

I would like to achieve dynamic file saving to correspondant folder name using cells values in vba like so:

```
Sub Envoie_Formulaire()
        Dim MyFile1 As String
        Dim MyFile2 As String
        Dim MyFile3 As String
        Dim MyFile4 As String
        Dim MyFileDir As String
        Dim MyFile As String
        MyFile1 = Range("D2").Text
        MyFile2 = Range("E2").Text
        MyFile3 = Range("F2").Text
        MyFile4 = Range("G2").Text
        MyFileDir = MyFile1 + MyFile2
        MyFile = MyFile1 + MyFile2 + MyFile3 + MyFile4
       ' Do not display the message about overwriting the existing file.
     
       ' Save the active workbook with the name of the
       ' active workbook. Save it on the E drive to a folder called
       ' "User" with a subfolder called "JoeDoe."
       ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:"\\localAdress\folder1\folder2\folder3\" & MyFileDir "\" & MyFile" "\"
       ' Close the workbook by using the following.
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

*** N.B:

```
D2 = the word  "BLOC-"
E2 = A letter from "A" to "N"
F2 =the word "BUREAU"
G2=a number of office from "1 to 1000".
```

So i was saving the dynamic `filename "BLOC-XXX BUREAU-XXX"` to a static network directory (`\\localAdress\folder1\folder2\folder3\BLOC-A)`
Now i just want to call " BLOC-xxx" from user output in the first corresponding cells.

But the issue is a syntax error produced in the filename path ligne, when i added " & MyFileDir ""`.
Any suggestions to achieve that?

Comment: It's unclear what the content of `MyFile1`…`MyFile4` is. Please read [mcve] and give a full example including example input data and desired output.

Comment: Not so clear what you want accomplishing. Do you want saving the active workbook with names `MyFile1, Myfile2 etc.`? All of them in the same path ("\\localAdress\folder1\folder2\folder3\")? What `MyFile` wants to be? Anyhow, independent of the above clarification request,  you must set a workbook to be saved extension...

Comment: The content of MyFile1…MyFile4 are cells values(Cell D2,E2,F2,G2...)

Comment: This is the single clear issue in your question. How these strings to be used? Like subfolders name in building the path? Like different names for the workbook to be saved, in the same path? Or how else, if any of above suppositions are not what you intend?

Comment: @user2890510 no Cell D2,E2,F2,G2 are the referenced cells but the question was about the values of these cells. Please [edit] your question and add how the data looks like. One sentence in a comment is not enough to explain your issue properly. We need much more information about your data and the desired output. Explain **precisely and in words** what you want to do. [Edit] your question (don't use a comment).

Comment: MyfileDir is the dynamic part of the path to get from a "preset formatted" cells with data validation(and those paths are already in the final static directory\folder3. after that saving to those folders will require getting dynamic folder names(based on the predefined values , the user types on those cells.

Comment: Again: Please tell us these values you are talking about. Give us some **real** example not only fictive descriptions of your variables. What are these "predefined values" **exactly**? [Edit] your question and add a full example data for what is in these cells.

Comment: I still do not understand anything... If, let us say, `MyFile1 = "Test1"` and `MyFile2 = "Test2"`, would you like to use them like `Test1\Test2` sequence in the path? Or a simple concatenated name like 'Test1Test2'? Independent of explaining this part, are those folders already created? Would you like the code to create them during the `SaveAs` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for sure a syntax error lies in that you have to change:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:
```

to:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=
```

and from your variable names I'd say that you should change:

```
MyFile = MyFile1 + MyFile2 + MyFile3 + MyFile4
```

to:

```
MyFile = MyFile3 & MyFile4
```

and therefore the final statement should be:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\localAdress\folder1\folder2\folder3\" & MyFileDir & "\" & MyFile
```

Comment: Well, there is definitely more wrong in the code than only that, if you have a look at the end of the line `& MyFile" "\"`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, I'm not excluding that

Comment: Well, then this is mora a comment than the solution/answer to the issue. The syntax error he got will not disappear changing what you suggest.

Comment: turned it into a more appropriate answer content

Comment: better ^^ but `MyFileDir "\"` is still missing an `&` and the `"` in the end is too much. Sorry for beeing so demanding ;)

Comment: @user2890510, place a breakpoint (F9) at line `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=...` and run the macro. Once the code stops there open the Immediate Window (CTRL-G) and type `?"\\localAdress\folder1\folder2\folder3\" & MyFileDir & "\" & MyFile` and press return: does the outcome please you?

Comment: saving filename only like so is actually working correctly` ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\localAdress\folder1\folder2\folder3\" & MyFile ` , problem is how to add the MyFileDir to the path after\folder3.

Comment: why not use `MyFileDir' then?

Comment: If i do so...then what i would save in that directory?  MyFile is the name of a file and MyFileDir is a part of the path to that file 2 different things.

Comment: I mean, if you use `MyFileDir = MyFile1 & MyFile2` and  `MyFile = MyFile3 & MyFile4` then would `"\\localAdress\folder1\folder2\folder3\" & MyFileDir & "\" & MyFile` yeald the correct string? If no, why?